# Injecting mongodb connection in nestJs not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to do a simple connection with my localhost:

I don't want to use Models or Schemas because the data structure is totally dynamic so I want to work with the native Mongoose Connection

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/nestjs')],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(@InjectConnection() private connection: Connection){}

  getConnection() {
    return this.connection;
  }
}
```

**app.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  async getConnection() {
    const connection  = await this.appService.getConnection();
    return connection;
  }
}
```

The connection object I recieve has no collections and no data (on my Robo3T I have collections with data)
Something like:

```
base:Mongoose {connections: Array(2), models: {…}, modelSchemas: {…}, options: {…}, _pluralize: ƒ}
client:MongoClient {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, s: {…}, topology: NativeTopology}
collections:{}
config:{autoIndex: true}
db:Db {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 3, _maxListeners: undefined, s: {…}, serverConfig: <accessor>}
host:'localhost'
id:1
models:{}
name:'nestjs'
options:null
otherDbs:(0) []
pass:undefined
plugins:(0) []
port:27017
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you connected to `mongodb://localhost/nestjs` to see that there are collections there?

Comment: yes @JayMcDoniel, as I said if I connect with Robo3T I can see all collections and data

Comment: I'm not sure if the connection is aware of the collections if you dont create and provide schemas. Have you tried crreating schemas to map with the data in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You need also import each collection with `MongooseModule.forFeature` method.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/nestjs'),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'CollectionName', schema: CollectionSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And then you could use it

```js
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(@InjectModel('CollectionName') private model: Model<any>){}

  findAll() {
    return this.model.find().exec();
  }
}
```

You can find [more information here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb)

Comment: ok, I got it, but how should be the Schema if the data structure is different from one document to another? I would like to be able to fetch all data no matter the Schema properties